# wordpress page redirect to 404 after changing the site

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I created a wordpress site, you can check it here http://www.enterhelix.com/shan/wordpress4.5/ , as I wanted it to be in a separate domain, so I created a domain http://www.pioneersurgicalsystems.in/ and copied all files and folder in the root of pioneersurgicalsystems.in including DATABASE. If you open pioneersurgicalsystems.in/ in your browser it will open, but if you click in any categories then you will be redirected to 404 page. After Googling I found a solution and edit `config.php` file and added

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.pioneersurgicalsystems.in');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.pioneersurgicalsystems.in');
```

and edited `functions.php` file of my theme and added the following code

```
update_option('siteurl', 'http://www.pioneersurgicalsystems.in');
update_option('home', 'http://www.pioneersurgicalsystems.in');
```

But still it does not work, everything is okay and working fine in the first link, but it is not working in the second link in which I want the site to be hosted, can anyone help me..?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please save permalink again?

**Step 1 :** Goto `wp-admin->setting->permalinks` 
**Steps 2 :** After save changes

[image: Permalink]

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to login in admin and only home page is open. other pages in not able to open then please first login to admin. and then from setting menu go permalinks menu and there from first select other option again select format (like post name) which you want like this way new `.htaccess` is created your problem will solved.try this your problem will solved

Answer (score 0):

go to `Settings->permalinks` save your Permalink Settings.